# Can we make it more plain to recruiters that we're not open to relocation?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The preference for being open to relocation is a checkbox, and if you don't check it, nothing about relocation shows up in your profile.  Evidently recruiters can't understand that a lack of "I am open to relocation" is the same thing as "I am not open to relocation", and so every single contact I've gotten through Careers is for a job that I would have to relocate for.  Can we make it more obvious to the recruiters (especially ones from Amazon) that we have not checked that box on purpose?

Comment: Not to name names, but especially the ones from Amazon :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out Paul. I think rather than making the assumption that those who have not filled in the box are definitively not welcome to relocation positions (which is certainly not the case), that we should allow users to explicitly state that preference in the negative.

This is by no means a hard rule that we would follow in other circumstances (forcing the user to state the negative case).  However in this instance, the lack of a complete profile in a section many users could accidentally overlook could cause the user to miss out on some excellent opportunities.

Comment: I appreciate that for some people, the lack of a checkmark in that box might mean "I forgot to go into that option to check it".  But I think most people it's a binary decision - either they're open to relocation or they're not.

Comment: I feel uncomfortable putting something on someone's profile that says: "I am not willing to relocate" when they haven't actually told us that, but rather left a field blank.  I'm thinking 3 radio buttons: Open to Relocation, Not Open to Relocation, No preference (which is the default, and means nothing goes on your profile).

Comment: The caption for "no preference" should be "feel free to tempt me"